# Pandas Error: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Tags: python, pandas

My question seems duplicate as I found different questions with the same error as follows:

> [Pandas: grouping a column on a value and creating new column headings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44847747/pandas-grouping-a-column-on-a-value-and-creating-new-column-headings)
>
> [Python/Pandas - ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45825381/python-pandas-valueerror-index-contains-duplicate-entries-cannot-reshape)
>
> [Pandas pivot produces "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46528599/pandas-pivot-produces-valueerror-index-contains-duplicate-entries-cannot-resh)

I tried all the solutions presented on those posts, but none worked. I believe the error maybe be caused by my dataset format, which has Strings instead of numbers and possible duplicate entires. Here follows an example of my Dataset:

| protocol_no | activity | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1586212 | walk | twice a day |
| 1586212 | drive | 5 km |
| 1586212 | drive | At least 30 min |
| 1586212 | sleep | NaN |
| 1586212 | eat | 1500 calories |
| 2547852 | walk | NaN |
| 2547852 | drive | NaN |
| 2547852 | eat | 3200 calories |
| 2547852 | eat | Avoid pasta |
| 2547852 | sleep | At least 10 hours |

The output I'm trying to achieve is:

| protocol_no | walk | drive | sleep | eat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1586212 | twice a day | 5km | NaN | 1500 calories |
| 2547852 | NaN | NaN | 3200 calories | At least 10 hours |

I tried using pivot and pivot_table with a code like this:

```
df.pivot(index="protocol_no", columns="activity", values="description")
```

But I'm still getting this error:

```
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Have no idea what is going wrong, so any help will be helpful!

**EDIT:**

I noticed my data contains duplicate entires as stated by the error and by @DYZ and @SeaBean users. So I've edited the database example and provided the correct answer for my dataset as well. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I executed your pivot statement on the provided data and got no error messages. Have you used the same data for your experiment?

Comment: Not really. My data is strictly confidential, so I can't share it. I provided a similar example, but as you have stated, it wasn't enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using [`.piviot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with `aggfunc='first'` (or something similar) if you get duplicate index error when using `.pivot()`

```
df.pivot_table(index="protocol_no", columns="activity", values="description", aggfunc='first')
```

This is a common situation when the column you set as `index` has duplicated values.  Using `aggfunc='first'`  (or sometimes `aggfunc='sum'` depending on condition) most probably can solve the problem.

**Result:**

```
activity    drive            eat              sleep         walk
protocol_no                                                     
1586212      5 km  1500 calories                NaN  twice a day
2547852       NaN  3200 calories  At least 10 hours          NaN
```

### Edit

Based on your latest edit with duplicate entries, you can just modify the solution above by changing the `aggfunc` function above, as follows:

```
df.pivot_table(index="protocol_no", columns="activity", values="description", aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna()))
```

Here, we change the `aggfunc` from `'first'` to `lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna())`.  It achieves the the same result as your desired output without adding multiple lines of codes.

**Result:**

```
activity                    drive                        eat              sleep         walk
protocol_no                                                                                 
1586212      5 km At least 30 min              1500 calories                     twice a day
2547852                            3200 calories Avoid pasta  At least 10 hours
```

Comment: Your solution worked on my data. Could you please explain more about what "first" does on aggregation?

Comment: @GuilhermeNoronha  Right, this is expected.  Most of the time `first` works well in this case. The `first` as aggregation function here is somewhat the same as the `GroupBy.first`(https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) function and sometimes we use `pivot_table` interchangeably with `groupby()` function as well.  Here, `first` is to get the first in group in case of multiple (duplicated) values in group.

Comment: @GuilhermeNoronha  The group here is the `protocol_no`, `activity`, `description` combination. If you have description for a particular `protocol_no` for an `activity`, then it will get the only `description`. (This is the most common use case).  In case you have multiple descriptions for one `protocol_no` and `activity` combination, it will take the first description.  As this case is relatively much rarer, `first` most probably can get our desired results.

Comment: Hi @GuilhermeNoronha  Seen your edit mentioning your data has duplicate entries.  So, how would you like to deal with it ?   One common way to solve this is to aggregate the multiple entries into one.  Let me know if you want to do so.  I can give you some hint on slightly fine-tuning the code above to consolidate/aggregate the duplicate entries into one.

Comment: Hi SeaBean. I just posted an answer based on the insights you and DYZ gave to me. I used the groupby to aggregate the duplicated entries and pivoted later. Anyway, thank you very much. The insights you gave to me was essential to find the best solution. :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNoronha  I seen your solution but it seems a little bit clumsy (sorry to say so). You can actually do it much simpler.  I am editing my solution with just little change to achieve the same result you want.  You will see it soon.

Comment: @GuilhermeNoronha  See my edit above.  Here's the power of using `.pivot_table()` with `aggfunc`.  It can achieve quite a lot of features/functions you want.  Try the new code and let me know how you think of it.  :-)

Comment: Indeed your solutions is much better than mine. I'll going to accept it. Thank you again for taking your time to help me. :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNoronha  You're welcome!  You could have asked me whether could  fine-tune my solution for your new finding of duplicate entries. Then you could save your time devising the  codes.  Anyway, it's still good you have taken a chance to think it by yourself.  Overall, you should have learned more by doing this exercise!   Happy programming and have a nice day!  :-)

Comment: Of course, I learned! And learned much more with your solution as well... :)

Answer (score 0):

Although the SeaBean answer worked on my data, I took a look into my data and noticed it really contained duplicated entires (as the example in my question I edited later). To deal with this, the best solution is to do a join with those duplicate entries.

**1-** Before the join, I needed to remove the NaNs of my Dataset. Otherwise it will raise another error:

```
df["description"].fillna("", inplace=True)
```

**2-** Then I executed the grouby function joining the duplicate entries:

```
df = df.groupby(["protocol_no", "activity"], as_index=False).agg({"description": " ".join})
```

**3-** The last, but not the least, I executed the pivot as I have intended to do in my question:

```
df.pivot(index="protocol_no", columns="activity", values="description")
```

**4-** Voilà, the result:

| protocol_no | drive | eat | sleep | walk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1586212 | 5 km At least 30 min | 1500 calories |  | twice a day |
| 2547852 |  | 3200 calories Avoid pasta | At least 10 hours |  |

**5-** The info of my dataset using `df.info()`

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2 entries, 1586212 to 2547852
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   drive   2 non-null      object
 1   eat     2 non-null      object
 2   sleep   2 non-null      object
 3   walk    2 non-null      object
dtypes: object(4)
memory usage: 80.0+ bytes
```

Hope It helps someone and many thanks to SeaBean and DYZ insights. :)

Comment: See my edit above for a simpler solution to this :-)